How do I use my theme for VS Code in Cursor? (Or does it not work?)
I've made a theme in this https://themes.vscode.one website that I found. It allowed me - or at least I thought - to make a theme. In Cursor (a fork of VS Code), it doesn't work. I haven't tried doing it in normal VS Code, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. I packaged it successfully (said vsce), so I have no idea why it wouldn't work.
I've tried repackaging it and adding other metadata 2 times, but it still didn't work. I even uploaded it to the extension marketplace for VS Code and tried installing it that way, but it still didn't work. I edited the JSON file for the settings to make it set my theme as the default, but that ended up just giving the default theme.
If anyone with VS Code could test it out and see if it works, that would help. The theme's address on VS Code is: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ferret.PURPLEX
I would give the code, but the code is too long to fit.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try to add your theme in Preference:Open User Settings => add "workbench.colorTheme":"name of your theme"(you can find it in Preferences:Color Theme.
